# PHP/Java Bridge blank page

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I'm trying to install PHP/Java Bridge in my Mac OS X Yosemite, but without success.

- I just have installed tomcat;
- I just just deploy JavaBridge.war to webapps directory;
- I just have installed php 5.

When I try to access the URL http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/test.php I'm getting a blank page.

I try to execute the command below that is describe in PHP Java Bridge FAQ, but it`s returning an error.

```
echo '<?php require_once("http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc"); echo java("java.lang.System")->getProperties();?>' | php -n -d allow_url_include=On
```

Error:

```
Warning: require_once(http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
 in - on line 1

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.7/lib/php') in - on line 1
```

Can you help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution!
I install Tomcat 7 instead Tomcat 8 and it works perfectly!

Thanks

Comment: in that case you should "just just" accept your own answer.